# Cannot convert method group "List" to non-delegate type

Tags: c#, nhibernate

```
public object Execute(UpdateUserStatusMessage message)
{

    IList<UserPreferredAccount> CustomerList = null;

    var query = CPSession.CreateSQLQuery("exec CP.CP_USR_CNTCT_CSTMR_SELECT :userId ");
    query.SetInt32("userId", message.CpUserCntctId);
    query.SetResultTransformer(Transformers.AliasToBean(typeof(UserPreferredAccount)));

    var model = new UpdateUserStatusModel
      {
        UserId = message.CpUserCntctId,
        UserPreferredAccounts =  query.List<UserPreferredAccount>
      };

  return model;
}
```

Here is the UpdateUserStatusModel:

```
    public class UpdateUserStatusModel{
        public int UserId {set; get;}
        public IList<UserPreferredAccount> UserPreferredAccounts{set; get;}
}
```

It gives me the error as described in title, I think both of them are the same type tho.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need parentheses and no semicolon:

```
UserPreferredAccounts =  query.List<UserPreferredAccount>()
```